# Unable to switch between application windows by ALT+Tab and clicking on icons after upgrading from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, cisco-vpn-client

I have updated my PC from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 on 7 Feb. Most things were working fine except a few pretty much annoying features, including a problem when switching between windows using methods including clicking on taskbar, using ALT+Tab and using the Task View.

**Phenomenon**

This happens in various applications including Chrome, Word and Acrobat Reader, Putty, and even Command Prompt. For example, when I am using Microsoft Word 2016 (not limited to this app) and I would like to switch to another window of Chrome by using the ALT+Tab shortcut or clicking the icon on the taskbar, the Chrome window sometimes shows up momentarily, but later it returns to the MS Word window and then the Word window goes out of focus. For most of the time now, the window simply stay stuck there without going away.

From the most recent test, I opened Chrome and Event Viewer (or any other apps such as Firefox or Word) at the same time. When I clicked on the Event Viewer icon continuously, it can show up and hide as normal. However, when I did the same to the Chrome icon, the Chrome window ALWAYS hides under the other windows (when the issue occurs).

Also, when I clicked the "Show desktop" button, some apps (e.g. Event Viewer in this case) stayed there. Sometimes I was able to "force" the desktop to be showed but when I clicked to open Chrome again, the Event Viewer app also showed up in the back at the same time. I am also unable to hide the Chrome window just by clicking on the Chrome window.

**Work done trying to solve the problem**

- A repair upgrade using the ISO provided on the Microsoft web page but the problem returns again.
- `sfc /scannow` but no problems were found
- `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` but no changes to the
  problem
- Reinstalled Chrome and Office, which were affected by the problem.
- Removed Cốc Cốc (a Vietnamese browser). The problem disappeared for
  some time before it reappears after a DRIVER POWER STATE FAILURE Blue
  Screen of Death
- Checked Windows update and everything was up to date
- Tried using ALT + Esc combination, but sometimes some applications
  were still stuck over the one that I want to focus on.
- Attempted to put my computer to a clean boot but it wasn't a long
  term solution to the problem
- Disconnect the VPN + Login to another account without signing out ->
  the issue is still there, though occuring less frequently
- Uninstall and reinstall the Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client
  but the issue seems not to be resolved.

**Computer specs**

Fujitsu AH544 with a Plextor PX-256M6S SSD plus 8 GB DDR3 RAM

**Recent software and hardware changes**

- Activation of Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client to connect to
  the VPN of my university
- Installed Open Hardware Monitor
- Encountered a few BSODs such as MEMORY_MANAGEMENT(ftser2k.sys) (due
  to external FTDI chip) and DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE

**Current hypotheses**

- An existent bug in Windows 10 OS (proved to be wrong as someone has
  already pointed out that the same upgrade from Win8.1 didn't lead to
  the problem in his computer)
- Compatibility issue with Problem with Chrome (unlikely as
  reinstalling Chrome didn't help)
- Compatibility issue with Problem with Cốc Cốc (maybe part of the
  problem but still existent)
- Compatibility issue with Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client
- Other driver issues?

Is there any way to solve this problem in a long-term manner? Also, what is the working principle behind the switching between application windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like some driver or software is messing with your system. You need to disable startup programs and uninstall any unusual devices you may have and then reinstall one by one, that way you can find the culprit. If you have vietnamese character input or something like that that could easily be the problem. You should also update all drivers for your computer to the latest version. It could be that the latest version of the drivers fixes this bug.